# Mocking getClass method with PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'd like to avoid mocking the getClass() method for a class but cannot seem to find any way around it. I'm trying to test a class that stores objects class types in a HashMap to a particular method to be used later. A brief example of this is:

```
public class ClassToTest {
    /** Map that will be populated with objects during constructor */
    private Map<Class<?>, Method> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Method>();

    ClassToTest() {
        /* Loop through methods in ClassToTest and if they return a boolean and 
           take in an InterfaceA parameter then add them to map */
    }

    public void testMethod(InterfaceA obj) {
        final Method method = map.get(obj.getClass());
        boolean ok;
        if (method != null) {
             ok = (Boolean) method.invoke(this, obj);
        }
        if (ok) {
            obj.run();
        }
    }

    public boolean isSafeClassA(final ClassA obj) {
        // Work out if safe to run and then return true/false
    }

    public boolean isSafeClassB(final ClassB obj) {
       // Work out if safe to run and then return true/fals 
    }

}

public interface InterfaceA {
   void run()
}

public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
   public void run() {
      // implements method here
   }
}

public class ClassB implements InterfaceA {
    public void run() {
       // implements method here
    }
}
```

I then have a JUnit test that looks a little like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassA.class})
public class ClassToTestTest {
    private final ClassToTest tester = new ClassToTest();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MockGateway.MOCK_GET_CLASS_METHOD = true;
        final ClassA classA = spy(new ClassA());
        doReturn(ClassA.class).when(classA).getClass();
        MockGateway.MOCK_GET_CLASS_METHOD = false;

        tester.testMethod(classA);
        verify(classA).run();
    }
}
```

My problem is although inside the test() method classA.getClass(); will return ClassA, once inside tester's testMethod() method it still returns the ClassA$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$... class and so my object useful will always be null.

Is there any way I can get around mocking the class or what do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that you should not be concerned with mocking getClass in the first place. Would you post some details about the test itself?

Comment: I agree, what are you trying to assert on? `testMethod()` is returning void so there isn't anything to `assert` on, and it doesn't look like you're updating the parameter object being passed in. Therefore I can only assume that there are some method calls from inside testMethod() that you wish to `verify` the interaction of

Comment: I wish to use mockito to verify that some actions inside the test happened. My map actually stores class type to a method so that I can call the method for each of the classes that implement the interface and then if the relevant method returns true (or there wasn't a method for the class) I want to ensure that some behaviour happened.

Comment: Can you write your test (requirements) in pseudo code, and/or provide more implementation code? It sounds like you're trying to use the `map` to implement some form of polymorphic behaviour which would not be a good approach. If the object being passed in implements InterfaceA then you should be coding to that `interface` and not try to determine its actual implementation class (e.g. ClassA) and then trying to execute a method that's not defined on the interface. Maybe I haven't understood correctly

Comment: I've tried to update my code to be a little more accurate to what I'm trying to test. I've ignored any exceptions that need catching/throwing though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, what a headache to get this code testable. The main issues are that you can't use mock objects as `key` objects into your calls to `map.get(obj.getClass())`, and you're trying to `invoke()` potentially mock objects for your testing. I had to refactor your class under test so that we can mock out the functionality/behaviour and be able to verify its behaviour.

So this is your new implementation to be tested with member variables decoupling the various pieces of functionailty and injected by the test class

```
public class ClassToTest {

    MethodStore methodStore;
    MethodInvoker methodInvoker;
    ClassToInvoke classToInvoke;
    ObjectRunner objectRunner;  

    public void testMethod(InterfaceA obj) throws Exception {

        Method method = methodStore.getMethod(obj);

        boolean ok = false;

        if (method != null) {
            ok = methodInvoker.invoke(method, classToInvoke, obj);
        }

        if (ok) {
            objectRunner.run(obj);
        }   
    }

    public void setMethodStore(MethodStore methodStore) {
        this.methodStore = methodStore;
    }

    public void setMethodInvoker(MethodInvoker methodInvoker) {
        this.methodInvoker = methodInvoker;
    }

    public void setObjectRunner(ObjectRunner objectRunner) {
        this.objectRunner = objectRunner;
    }

    public void setClassToInvoke(ClassToInvoke classToInvoke) {
        this.classToInvoke = classToInvoke;
    }
}
```

This is your test class that no longer requires PowerMock, because it [can't mock the Method class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011129/mocking-reflection-based-calls/9011651#9011651). It just returns a NullPointerException.

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest();

        ClassA inputA = new ClassA();

        // trying to use powermock here just returns a NullPointerException
//      final Method mockMethod = PowerMockito.mock(Method.class);
        Method mockMethod = (new ClassToInvoke()).getClass().getMethod("someMethod");   // a real Method instance

        // regular mockito for mocking behaviour    
        ClassToInvoke mockClassToInvoke = mock(ClassToInvoke.class);
        classToTest.setClassToInvoke(mockClassToInvoke);

        MethodStore mockMethodStore = mock(MethodStore.class);
        classToTest.setMethodStore(mockMethodStore);

        when(mockMethodStore.getMethod(inputA)).thenReturn(mockMethod);

        MethodInvoker mockMethodInvoker = mock(MethodInvoker.class);
        classToTest.setMethodInvoker(mockMethodInvoker);

        when(mockMethodInvoker.invoke(mockMethod,mockClassToInvoke, inputA)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

        ObjectRunner mockObjectRunner = mock(ObjectRunner.class);
        classToTest.setObjectRunner(mockObjectRunner);

        // execute test method      
        classToTest.testMethod(inputA);

        verify(mockObjectRunner).run(inputA);   
    }
}
```

The additional classes you require are as follows

```
public class ClassToInvoke {
    public void someMethod() {};
}

public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class ClassToInvoke {
    public void someMethod() {};
}

public class MethodInvoker {

    public Boolean invoke(Method method, Object obj, InterfaceA a) throws Exception {
         return (Boolean) method.invoke(obj, a);
    }
}

public class MethodStore {

    Map<Class<?>, Method> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Method>();

    public Method getMethod(InterfaceA obj) {
        return map.get(obj);
    }
}
```

Put all this into your IDE and it will pass with a Green bar...woohoo!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is actually that `getClass` is `final` in `Object`, so you can't stub it with Mockito.  I can't think of a good way around this.  There is one possibility, that you might consider.

Write a utility class that has a single method

```
public Class getClass(Object o){
    return o.getClass();
}
```

and refactor the class that you're testing, so that it uses an object of this utility class, instead of calling `getClass()` directly.  Then, make it possible to inject the utility object, either with a special package-private constructor, or with a setter method.

```
public class ClassToTest{
    private UtilityWithGetClass utility;
    private Map<Class<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public ClassToTest() {
        this(new UtilityWithGetClass());
    }

    ClassToTest(UtilityWithGetClass utility){
        this.utility = utility;
        // Populate map here
    }

    // more stuff here
}
```

Now, in your test, make a mock of the object and stub `getClass`.  Inject the mock into the class that you're testing.

Comment: I thought using PowerMockito allowed me to stub final methods though?

Comment: Yes PowerMockito does. I'm still struggling to see what you're trying to test, and therefore I can't see how this answer is useful. Wrapping getClass() doesn't feel like the right thing to be doing.

Comment: I want to verify that a method in the class I pass in as InterfaceA (i.e. run) gets called in this method given specific scenarios. The map actually holds the objects class type to some saftey methods and depending on the result of these methods (they return a boolean) calls the run method in the class.

Comment: I know that there are limits on WHICH final methods PowerMockito can help with.  I don't know whether `getClass` is among the ones that you can't stub.  I would say "try it and see", but it seems that you've already tried it and seen.  What do you mean when you say "the class I pass in as InterfaceA" - surely the object that you're passing is not in fact a class?  Or is it?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with similar question, too. I think you should add ClassToTest.class to @PrepareForTest, because you want to mock the getClass() function in that class